# how to put a hook in terraform main.tf as shell script to enable the additional EBS volume for delete_on_termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

`I need a help to create the hook in shell script under main.tf file so that whenever i spin the server and additional ebs volume should get enabled for delete`*`on`*`termination. below i have shared the code which i have created as shellscript.`

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["bash", "-x"]
    command = <<EOT
      #!/bin/bash -x
      echo "Getting device name..."
      DEVICE_NAME=$(lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '/^sdf[b-z]/ && $2=="" {print "/dev/"$1}' | head -1)
      echo "Device name is: $DEVICE_NAME"
      echo "Getting volume ID..."
      VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID Name=attachment.device,Values=$DEVICE_NAME --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text)
      echo "Volume ID is: $VOLUME_ID"
      if [[ -n "$VOLUME_ID" ]]; then
        aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"$DEVICE_NAME\", \"Ebs\":{\"VolumeId\":\"${aws_ebs_volume.this[each.key].id}\",\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"
      else
        echo "Failed to find EBS volume attached to instance $INSTANCE_ID with device name $DEVICE_NAME" >&2
        exit 1
      fi
    EOT
  }
}
```

also i have shared the error message which iit shows while running spinning the server.

```
module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"]: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec): Executing: ["bash" "-x" "      #!/bin/bash -x\n      echo \"Getting device name...\"\n      DEVICE_NAME=$(lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '/^sdf[b-z]/ && $2==\"\" {print \"/dev/\"$1}' | head -1)\n      echo \"Device name is: $DEVICE_NAME\"\n      echo \"Getting volume ID...\"\n      VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID Name=attachment.device,Values=$DEVICE_NAME --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text)\n      echo \"Volume ID is: $VOLUME_ID\"\n      if [[ -n \"$VOLUME_ID\" ]]; then\n        aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --block-device-mappings \"[{\\\"DeviceName\\\": \\\"$DEVICE_NAME\\\", \\\"Ebs\\\":{\\\"VolumeId\\\":\\\"vol-091235c2b5d98d1c6\\\",\\\"DeleteOnTermination\\\":true}}]\"\n      else\n        echo \"Failed to find EBS volume attached to instance $INSTANCE_ID with device name $DEVICE_NAME\" >&2\n        exit 1\n      fi\n"]

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec): bash:       #!/bin/bash -x

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       echo "Getting device name..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       DEVICE_NAME=$(lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '/^sdf[b-z]/ && $2=="" {print "/dev/"$1}' | head -1)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       echo "Device name is: $DEVICE_NAME"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       echo "Getting volume ID..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID Name=attachment.device,Values=$DEVICE_NAME --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       echo "Volume ID is: $VOLUME_ID"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       if [[ -n "$VOLUME_ID" ]]; then

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):         aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"$DEVICE_NAME\", \"Ebs\":{\"VolumeId\":\"vol-091235c2b5d98d1c6\",\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       else

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):         echo "Failed to find EBS volume attached to instance $INSTANCE_ID with device name $DEVICE_NAME" >&2

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):         exit 1

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec):       fi

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"] (local-exec): : No such file or directory

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] ╷

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ Warning: Deprecated attribute

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ 

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │   on .terraform/modules/S3_TF_TESTING_BUCKET_FDL001/modules/s3/main.tf line 27, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this":

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │   27:       acceleration_status,

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ 

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ The attribute "acceleration_status" is deprecated. Refer to the provider

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ documentation for details.

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ 

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ (and 2 more similar warnings elsewhere)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] ╵

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] ╷

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ Error: local-exec provisioner error

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ 

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │   with module.EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING.aws_volume_attachment.this["_0~_0"],

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │   on .terraform/modules/EC2_TERRAFORMTESTING/modules/ec2/main.tf line 197, in resource "aws_volume_attachment" "this":

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │  197:   provisioner "local-exec" {

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ 

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ Error running command '      #!/bin/bash -x

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Getting device name..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       DEVICE_NAME=$(lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '/^sdf[b-z]/ && $2=="" {print "/dev/"$1}' | head -1)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Device name is: $DEVICE_NAME"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Getting volume ID..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID Name=attachment.device,Values=$DEVICE_NAME --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Volume ID is: $VOLUME_ID"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       if [[ -n "$VOLUME_ID" ]]; then

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │         aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"$DEVICE_NAME\", \"Ebs\":{\"VolumeId\":\"vol-091235c2b5d98d1c6\",\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       else

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │         echo "Failed to find EBS volume attached to instance $INSTANCE_ID with device name $DEVICE_NAME" >&2

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │         exit 1

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       fi

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │ ': exit status 127. Output: bash:       #!/bin/bash -x

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Getting device name..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       DEVICE_NAME=$(lsblk -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT | awk '/^sdf[b-z]/ && $2=="" {print "/dev/"$1}' | head -1)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Device name is: $DEVICE_NAME"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Getting volume ID..."

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       VOLUME_ID=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID Name=attachment.device,Values=$DEVICE_NAME --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId' --output text)

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       echo "Volume ID is: $VOLUME_ID"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       if [[ -n "$VOLUME_ID" ]]; then

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │         aws ec2 modify-instance-attribute --instance-id $INSTANCE_ID --block-device-mappings "[{\"DeviceName\": \"$DEVICE_NAME\", \"Ebs\":{\"VolumeId\":\"vol-091235c2b5d98d1c6\",\"DeleteOnTermination\":true}}]"

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.099Z] │       else

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.100Z] │         echo "Failed to find EBS volume attached to instance $INSTANCE_ID with device name $DEVICE_NAME" >&2

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.100Z] │         exit 1

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.100Z] │       fi

[2023-04-11T21:23:30.100Z] │ : No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way instead of specifying `delete_on_termination` in the Terraform resource configuration?

Comment: Hello Mark,
Thanks for your respond, The problem is the way we have set up our main.tf is not supporting EBS  delete_on_termination part. its working fine for the root volume, therefor we are trying to add a hook to make this work. Please let me know if you have any solutions. 

Regards 
Ranjeet

Comment: Show all your code then. The way you are doing this is absolutely the worst way possible, and you should be examining your terraform code to figure out how to do it properly. We could probably help you with that if you showed the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using, with a provisioner that calls the AWS CLI, is extremely error prone, and entirely unneeded. Terraform provides a way to set the `delete_on_termination` setting on any block devices created as part of an EC2 instance creation.

To specify `delete_on_termination` in Terraform for EBS volumes created during an EC2 instance creation, you do that like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  # Your other instance settings here

  # To specify settings for the root block device
  root_block_device {
    # Other block device settings
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  # To specify settings for additional block devices
  ebs_block_device {
    # Other block device settings
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
}
```

---

Also, note that the default value for [this setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/-/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#delete_on_termination) is `true`, so your script was entirely unnecessary anyway.